# page control buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I'm doing an project, where I need make an PageControl with 3 images. It's woking, but the image of the page controll, that three little circles appear only on first image. what I'm doing wrong?

```
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

CGRect frame;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;


//INICIO SCROLLVIEW DE FOTOS

//Fotos ---------
NSArray *imagens = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foto1.png",@"foto1.png",@"foto1.png", nil];
//Fotos ---------

for (int i = 0; i < imagens.count; i++) {
    CGRect frame;

    frame.origin.x = self.listaFotos.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.listaFotos.frame.size;

    //Imagem
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = CGSizeMake(491, 330);

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagens objectAtIndex:i]];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = frame;

    [self.listaFotos addSubview:imageView];

    frame.origin.x = self.listaFotos.frame.size.width * i;

}

self.listaFotos.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.listaFotos.frame.size.width * imagens.count, self.listaFotos.frame.size.height);

self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
self.pageControl.numberOfPages = imagens.count;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably adding the page control to the scroll view. You should add it to the scroll view's superview, i.e. as a sibling of it, and on top of the scroll view. That way it won't scroll with the scroll view.